# Using articles with proper nouns

Tags: articles

I recently came upon these two curious sentences:

> 1. " I believe it was a young Barack Obama who said...."
> 2. "The young Joyce already showed signs of the genius that was to be fulfilled in Ulysses"

Why is the definite article not used in the first sentence? What's the difference between the usage of 'Young' in these two sentences?

I also came upon these:

> 3. "I like Freda, but the Freda this evening is boring"
> 4. "The Chicago of my youth..." , "The Dublin of Joyce is still there....".

The book says the first sentence is incorrect but the next two sentences are legitimate. How is that? What's the difference?

Comment: Both your first two examples would be perfectly valid (and so far as I'm concerned, would mean *exactly* the same) if you reversed the choices of definite / indefinite article. But I'd guess only the ***definite*** article *(**the**)* is syntactically valid with your second pair. I can't articulate any grammar-based *reason* for this difference, but it's difficult if not impossible to contrive contexts where ***a*** would be acceptable with that second pair.